# Can there be a countable transitive model satisfying the same $MK$ theory as $V$?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

A little while ago, I asked whether or not there could be a countable transitive model satisfying the same $ZFC$ theory as $V$ (assuming that we're working within some $V$, or (if you like) that there is a unique maximal universe of sets denoted by `$V$'). The answer was emphatically *yes*, in fact such a theory is given by Feferman. What we can do is add a constant symbol $M$ to the language of $ZFC$, and then add the following axioms:

(1) $M$ is countable and transitive.

(2) (Axiom Scheme) For every $\phi$ in the language of set theory (without $M$), $\phi \leftrightarrow \phi^M$.

This latter axiom has to be a scheme; if it were done with a single axiom we would violate Tarski's Theorem. However, the extensions is quite weak---it turns out to be a conservative extensions of $ZFC$ (by the Reflection Theorem). One can also get a similar effect with a truth predicate: we add a truth predicate, add Tarski's $T$-axioms, and then using reflection in the expanded language get a $V_\alpha$ which we then Skolemise and Collapse to get a countable transitive model that is an elementary substructure of $V$.

My question: Move to the case where we consider $MK$ class theory over $V$, a two-sorted first-order theory of sets and classes with an impredicative class comprehension scheme. Suppose we have a "philosophically acceptable" interpretation of the variables so we can give $MK$ its `full' semantics (or just work in a $(V_\kappa, \in, V_\kappa +1)$ with $\kappa$ inaccessible if you have foundational queasiness). Can we pull the same trick? i.e. Is the axiom system:

(1) $M$ is countable and transitive.

(2) (Axiom Scheme) For every $\phi$ in the language of $MK$ (without $M$), $\phi \leftrightarrow \phi^M$.

My worry: Insistence on the full semantics for $MK$ ensures that there's uncountably many sentences satisfied by $V$, and so you can't have such a countable transitive model; in any $(M, \in, C) \models MK$, $C$ is always countable.

Similarly, the truth predicate tactic seems dodgy; such a predicate is going to be third-order, not just second-order.

However, I'm mindful that I'm playing fast and loose here---$MK$ is still just a garden variety countable first-order language, so I wonder if there can be a countable transitive model that is an elementary substructure of $V$ as regards $MK$.

[EDIT: I should say more about what I'm interested in. This subdivides the question a bit:

1. Can there be such a $(M, \in , C)$ when $C$ is countable.
2. Can there be an elementary substructure of $V$ (either countable or uncountable) $(M, \in, C)$.

Sneaky aim: I'm trying to figure out whether there's a relevant difference (in either set-sized or countable structures) between having an elementary submodel of $V$ relative to $ZFC$ vs. relative to $MK$.]

Comment: In what sense are there "uncountably many sentences satisfied by $V$"?  Unless you're allowing parameters, there are only countably many sentences period.

Comment: Do class quantifiers restricted to $M$ range over all subsets of $M$? If so, then the answer is `no'. Any transitive set satisfying MK is an inaccessible rank. In general, any model $M$ satisfying MK has as its transitive collapse an inaccessible rank.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey. Exactly. I think I'm smuggling in parameters in my head when I use the term `full semantics'. In that sense though, it's not much different from $ZFC$, there's uncountably many sentences of $ZFC$ satisfied by $V$ if you let parameters in.

Comment: @GME, I think the answer has to be `no' (such a model would not then be `countable' in a strict sense, even if (per impossible) the domain of first order quantifiers was countable). I'll update my question with a few clarifications, thanks.

Comment: Ok. And do you want parameters from $M$ in the schema? If so, both class and set parameters?

Comment: Good question. The real reason I want to do this is I have an argument that a particular structure can be coded by a single class in $MK$. I want to reduce the theory to the countable, so I can do this by just sticking a predicate for that class into $ZFC$ and proceeding a la Feferman. But I'm wondering if this is all redundant as one could just do it with $MK$ straight up. I guess the answer to your question depends on whether or not my pet class (which I can't define here unfortunately - it's a bit tricky) needs a parameter.

Comment: If by "model of $MK$" you mean the usual first-order notion (so you aren't requiring any sort of special semantics for the classes of $M$), then literally everything you've said about $ZFC$ applies in exactly the same way to $MK$.  There is nothing at all that goes wrong.  The fact that your ambient model $V$ happens to have some sort of full semantics has nothing to do with the argument.

Comment: What Eric said. If you ban parameters (as you should), then getting such a model is a simple LS on your $V_{\kappa+1}$ followed by transitive collapse. That will give you a countable, transitive, model elementarily equivalent to $V_{\kappa+1}$.

Comment: @GME So what you are saying is that it is consistent with an inaccessible that there is a model of KM with a countable transitive model of KM that satisfies the same theory (by taking elementary substructure of $(V_{\kappa+1},\in))$. It seems unclear how to do it without an inaccessible.

Comment: @VictoriaGitman Right. To do it in the theory MK, rather than a standard model of it, is slightly tougher. I would imagine it depends on whether we have some suitable choice principle for classes. If so, then for a finite set of formulas, we could do an LS construction picking class witnesses as we go and then cutting them down to size at the end before taking the transitive collapse. Does that sound right?

Comment: I tried to do it with a strong choice principle for classes, where you can reflect any finite number of second-order formulas down to a coded collection of classes (a collection $\mathcal S$ of classes is coded if there is a class $S=\langle S_\xi\mid \xi<ORD\rangle$ such that the $S_\xi$ are precisely the members of $\mathcal S$), but I don't see any way to get it down to a set.

Comment: @VictoriaGitman So, I was thinking that we'd construct an $\omega$ sequence of classes $X_n$ which code (i) a set $x_n$ and (ii) classes $Y_i$ indexed by a set $I_n$. Then, at $X_{n+1}$ we finite sequence of sets and classes $y_0,...,y_n,Y_i,...,Y_j$ coded by $X_n$ and pick the least $x$ such that $\phi(x, y_0,...,y_n,Y_i,...,Y_j)$ and put it in $x_{n+1}$, and pick the least $X$ such that  $\phi(X, y_0,...,y_n,Y_i,...,Y_j)$ and let $Y_{\langle \phi, y_0,...,y_n,i,...,j \rangle}$  be coded in $X_{n+1}$. Then $x_{n+1}$ and $I_{n+1}$ are sets and no bigger than $|\omega \cup x_n\cup I_n|$....

Comment: @VictoriaGitman Finally, let $x_\omega = \bigcup_{n<\omega} x_n$ and $I_\omega = \bigcup_{n<\omega} I_n$. Then if we started with $X_0 = 0$,  $M = \langle x_\omega, \{Y_i\cap x_\omega: i\in I_\omega\}\rangle$ will be countable, and such that $M\vDash \phi(x, Y_i\cap  x_\omega)$ iff $\phi(x, Y_i)$. We then just take $M$'s transitive collapse.

Comment: (For the last claim, we need to make sure that in addition to our finite set of formulas, MM also reflects Extensionality for classes. Also, I should have written "let $X = Y_{\langle n+1, \phi, y_0,...,y_n,i,...,j\rangle}$ be coded in $X_{n+1}$".)

Comment: @GME Yes, this looks right! So we just need dependent choice for classes. You should write up the answer with the details.

Comment: @VictoriaGitman Thanks, Victoria! Super busy at the mo (hence the sketch), but will write up tomorrow when I get chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on my sketch in the comments, here's a proof that axioms (1) and (2) (where $\phi$ has no parameters) are conservative over $MK$ plus the choice schema:

(CC) $\forall x\exists X\phi(x, X) \to \exists Y\forall x\phi(x, Y_x)$

where $Y_x = \{y:\langle x, y\rangle\in Y\}$, and the $\omega$-dependent choice schema:

(DC) $\forall X\exists Y\phi(X, Y) \to \exists Z\forall n\in\omega\phi(Z_n, Z_{n+1})$

See Victoria Gitman's slides [here](http://boolesrings.org/victoriagitman/files/2015/01/kelleymorse2.pdf) for more details.

The idea is to construct a witness to (1) and (2) for any finite collection $\phi_0,...,\phi_n$ of formulas. In what follows I will assume that these formulas are closed under subformulas, and that they contain $\exists x(x = y)$, $\exists X(X = Y)$, $\exists x(x\in X \wedge x\not\in Y)$.

Let $\mbox{dom}(X) = \{x: \exists y\langle x, y\rangle\in X\}$ and $\mbox{rng}(X) = \{y: \exists x\langle x, y\rangle\in X\}$, and let $X^1 = \mbox{dom}(X)$ and $X^2 = \mbox{dom(rng}(X))$. Say that $X$ is a *countable model* if $X^1$ and $X^2$ are countable. In other words, $X$ codes a countable set domain $X^1$ and a countable class domain $\{\mbox{rng}(X)_y: y\in X^2\}$.

Now, suppose $X$ is a countable model. By CC, there is a $Y^{\exists x/X\phi_i}$ such that whenever $\vec{x}\in X^1$, $\vec{y}\in X^2$, and $\exists x/X\phi_i(x/X,\vec{x},\vec{\mbox{rng}(X)_y})$, then:

$\phi_i(Y^{\exists x/X\phi_i}_{\langle \vec{x}, \vec{y}\rangle}, \vec{x}, \vec{\mbox{rng}(X)_y})$

and otherwise $Y^{\exists x/X\phi_i}_{\langle \vec{x}, \vec{y}\rangle} = \emptyset$.

For simplicity, here and below I assume that when $\exists x/X\phi_i$ takes a set witness, $Y^{\exists x/X\phi_i}_{\langle\vec{x}, \vec{y}\rangle}$ is the corresponding set. Then let $Z$ be such that:

$Z^1 = \{Y^{\exists x/X\phi_i}_{\langle \vec{x}, \vec{y}\rangle}: \vec{x}\in X^1 \wedge \vec{y}\in X^2, \mbox{for $\exists x/X\phi_i$ that take set witnesses}\}$

$\mbox{rng}(Z) = \{\langle \langle \exists x/X\phi_i, \vec{x},\vec{y}\rangle, z\rangle: z\in Y^{\exists x/X\phi_i}_{\langle \vec{x}, \vec{y}\rangle}, \mbox{for $\exists x/X\phi_i$ that take class witnesses}\}$

So $Z$ is a countable model closed under witnesses for the $\phi_i$ with parameters from $X$. From DC, it the follows that there is a countable sequence $Y$ of countable models such that $Y_0 = \emptyset$ and $Y_{n+1}$ is closed under witnesses for the $\phi_i$ with parameters from $Y_n$. Given such a sequence, let $Z$ be such that:

$Z^1 = \bigcup_{n\in\omega} Y^1_n$

$\mbox{rng}(Z) = \{\langle \langle n, x\rangle, y\rangle: \langle x, y\rangle\in \mbox{rng}(Y_n)\}$

It is then straightforward to verify that $Z$ is a countable model closed under witnesses for the $\phi_i$ for its parameters. It follows that $\phi_i^Z$ iff $\phi_i$ for parameters from $Z$ (where $\phi_i^Z$ is the result of restricting set quantifiers in $\phi_i$ to $Z^1$ and class quantifiers to $\{\mbox{rng}(Z)_y: y\in Z^2\}$). Finally, note that for the countable set model $M = \langle Z^1, \{Z^1\cap \mbox{rng}(Z)_y: y\in Z^2\}\rangle$, we have:

$M\vDash \phi_i(\vec{x},\vec{Z^1\cap \mbox{rng}(Z)_y})$ iff $\phi_i^Z(\vec{x},\vec{\mbox{rng}(Z)_y})$

It follows that the countable transitive collapse of $M$, $M'$, is elementarily equivalent to $V$ for sentences among the $\phi_i$. So $M'$ is our desired witness to (1) and (2).